# Combine multiple rows into one row with same number of columns

Tags: database, sum, rows

I have results that have multiple rows for priority counts for specific locations. I would like to simply turn those results into a single row to display the same information.

My current code is:

```
SELECT t.city_nm as CITY
              ,sum(case when h.priority = 1  then 1 else 0 end)as Priority1
              ,sum(case when h.priority = 2  then 1 else 0 end)as Priority2
              ,sum(case when h.priority = 3  then 1 else 0 end)as Priority3
from SHIPMENT h
INNER JOIN PET_EVT_LOG e 
on h.svc_id = e.svc_id
INNER JOIN LOCATION t
ON t.city_id = e.term_id
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER u
ON h.ship_cust = u.cust_id 
where u.cust_nm = 'CAL NATURAL'
            and e.evt_cd = 'ARRIVAL'
            and e.evt_dt_tm > date(current timestamp) - 7 day
GROUP BY t.city_nm, h.priority;
```

My results look like this:

```
CITY      Priority1  Priority 2  Priority3
Atlanta      7           0          0
Atlanta      0           25         0
Atlanta      0           0          3
Baltimore    3           0          0
Baltimore    0           12         0
Baltimore    0           0          1
Detroit      9           0          0
Detroit      0           32         0
Detroit      0           0          5
```

Where there is a number count in one row, the other two fields are ALWAYS 0, so they should easily be combined to produce results that look like this:

```
CITY      Priority1  Priority 2  Priority3
Atlanta      7           25         3
Baltimore    3           12         1
Detroit      9           32         5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try replacing

```
GROUP BY t.city_nm, h.priority;
```

by

```
GROUP BY t.city_nm;
```

Comment: Wow, I don't know how I missed that. Thank you very much. It worked great.